# How do I reset TextInput that is made as custom component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hello guys I have a custom component for TextInput and after I submit my form I want to reset the field but seem to not making any change.

Here is the component imported in my render;

```
<InputField
    customStyle={{ marginBottom: 30, marginTop: 20 }}
    textColor={colors.black}
    labelText="JOB TITLE"
    labelTextSize={14}
    labelColor={colors.black}
    borderBottomColor={borderColor}
    inputType="text"
    multiline={true}
    onChangeText={this.handleNameChange}
    showCheckmark={validName}
/>
```

Now the onChangeText function is related to this

```
handleNameChange(name) {
    const { validName } = this.state;
    this.setState({ name });
    if (!validName) {
      if (name.length >= 10) {
        this.setState({ validName: true });
      }
    } else if (name.length < 10) {
      this.setState({ validName: false });
    }
  }
```

And here is my actual TextInput implementation

```
onChangeText(text) {
   this.props.onChangeText(text);
   this.setState({ inputValue: text });
}

<TextInput
      style={[
        { color: inputColor, borderBottomColor: borderBottom },
        inputStyle,
        styles.inputField
      ]}
      secureTextEntry={secureInput}
      onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
      keyboardType={keyboardType}
      autoFocus={autoFocus}
      autoCorrect={false}
      underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
      placeholder={placeholder}
      defaultValue={inputValue}
      value={inputValue}
      editable={editable}
      multiline={multiline}
    />
```

So I want to reset the fields when I submit my form. I have tried by `setState({name: ""})` which is changing the state in render but not from component which is called inputValue

Comment: The value of TextInput is in value props right?, so if you want to reset the value of your TextInput you need to setState({value:""}), not setState({name:""}).

Answer (score 0):

It will stay the same because the state of the value is not automatically cleared. You need to use setState on the TextInput's value. So something like this.setState({ inputValue: '' }) should work.